# Does MySQL or MariaDB have in-memory database?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm doing unit/integration tests. SQLite doesn't support `RIGHT JOIN` and `FULL OUTER JOIN`. Is there any way to work with MySQL (or MariaDB) completely stored in memory? MySQL has MEMORY table engine, however this may generate inconsistency in my tests.

I need some alternative to :memory: from SQLite but with the same features as MySQL. My problem is performance. SQLite database in-memory speeds up my testing process, however some queries aren't compatible with SQLite. I also do not find it good practice to do the tests in SQLite if the production database is MariaDB.

Comment: The answer to your question is the MEMORY storage engine.  You need to be a bit clearer about what the issue is.  You could use another storage engine on an "in-memory" virtual disk, but that depends on your operating system.

Comment: Which inconsistencies?

Comment: First question is "Why?" as it's usually a bad plan to test in memory for what will be deployed on disk, and secondly, if you *really* need it in memory use a ramdisk.

Comment: MySQL and MariaDB do not have `FULL OUTER JOIN`, but it can be easily simulated.

Comment: Usually unit tests should not touch database at all, what you're doing is probably integration tests, for such ones I'd prefer to have standalone mysql server, so test suite in setup will create db, all tables, sample data and drop all of it during finalization

Comment: Let your MariaDB eat up more of your RAM and you won't have an issue as everything will be in memory.

Comment: @IlyaBursov I'm currently working this way (with Docker), but performance is still a very big berrier. The I/O in HDD makes the tests take 5x more time compared with SQLite in-memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few years of research and testing of different approaches to this question. The best way I found to deal with the problem was using Docker. More precisely using tmpfs volumes. This way I guarantee that the databases will not persist on the disk and will not suffer from I/O blocking.

For those interested, Docker has its own documentation on this type of volume: https://docs.docker.com/storage/tmpfs/

Answer (score 3):

MariaDB has [the MEMORY storage engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/memory-storage-engine/):

> It is best-used for read-only caches of data from other tables, or for temporary work areas.

That sounds exactly right for quick setup and teardown of a database during automated testing.

Comment: one of limitations is "BLOB or TEXT columns are not supported for MEMORY tables."

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hack with a systemd unit, which will copy the MariaDB/MySQL storage on a tmpfs.
It is written for a standard Ubuntu/Debian installation but should be adaptable for other environments. Add `sudo` where needed.

Risk of data loss: study thoroughly to see if it fits your use case.
(and also check the database size.)

```ini
# This systemd unit puts the MariaDB/MySQL storage on tmpfs and (tries to) sync
# it back at shutdown.

# Of course, in case of power failure or any problem preventing this
# unit to stop properly and sync back the data to disk : DATA LOSS.

# To install on Debian/Ubuntu :
# - apt install rsync
# - systemctl stop mariadb
# - write this content to /etc/systemd/system/mariadbontmpfs.service
# - systemctl enable mariadbontmpfs.service
# - systemctl start mariadbontmpfs.service
# - systemctl start mariadb

# This file is free software licensed under the WTFPL (v2)

[Unit]
Description=Put /var/lib/mysql on tmpfs before MariaDB/MySQL starts
Before=mariadb.service mysql.service
ConditionPathIsDirectory=/var/lib/mysql
ConditionPathExists=/usr/bin/rsync

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
Restart=no

# We double-check that MariaDB is not running before doing anything
ExecCondition=/bin/sh -c "systemctl --quiet is-active mariadb mysql && echo 'MariaDB or MySQL still active' && exit 255 || exit 0"

# If the ON-DISK directory doesn't exist, simply rename /var/lib/mysql to
# /var/lib/mysql.ON-DISK and recreate /var/lib/mysql
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "if [ ! -e /var/lib/mysql.ON-DISK ] ; then mv -v /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql.ON-DISK && mkdir -v /var/lib/mysql && chown -v mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql; fi"
# Mount the tmpfs
ExecStart=/bin/mount -v -t tmpfs -o uid=mysql,gid=mysql,mode=0755 none /var/lib/mysql
# Copy the ON-DISK content to the tmpfs
ExecStart=/usr/bin/rsync -avH --delete /var/lib/mysql.ON-DISK/ /var/lib/mysql/

# At stop :
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c "echo 'Syncing tmpfs:/var/lib/mysql to disk'"
ExecStop=/usr/bin/rsync -avH --delete /var/lib/mysql/ /var/lib/mysql.ON-DISK/
ExecStop=/bin/umount -v /var/lib/mysql
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c "rmdir -v /var/lib/mysql && mv -v /var/lib/mysql.ON-DISK /var/lib/mysql"
```

[Full file available here.](https://code.bugness.org/chl/scripts-admin-quickndirty-public/src/branch/master/systemd-units/mariadbontmpfs.service)